# How are android sms stored?.In a file system i.e message1.extension or in a database i.e sqlite

Tags: android

How are android sms messages stored?.Do the messages have a filename extension for instance message.extension or are they stored in some sort of database i.e sqlite?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sms and mms messages are stored in:

data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db

Comment: What sort of database is mmssms.db?.Sqlite?

Comment: This accepted answer suggests so http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored i shall have to test it.Thanks.